# Average value of list in Label.Text WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm a bit new in WinForms and having problem when I try to use Average() method on a list and saving it straight to the text of label (Label.Text).

```
this.label2.Text = MyList.Average().ToString();
```

My program is compiling fine, I see the result of above operation on the screen, but when I switch cards to Form1.cs[Design] and try to add some new elements, I can't see the window. Only what it's there is this error:

```
Method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Average' not found.
```

What is the cause of this problem? I would like to add something to my window but simply can't do this in Designer, only in code, which made WinForms unuseful.

Comment: Are you saying that you added that first line of code to the designer code file?  You shouldn't be modifying that code at all, unless it's to fix a mistake that the designer itself made and can't rectify on its own. That code needs to be executed at design time. How can the average of a list be calculated at design time when the list doesn't exist until run time? Put that code in the `Load` event handler of the form, so it gets executed at run time, after the form has been created and initialised.

Comment: Why do you want this to show at design time? At design time you can just put a hard-coded value but once you run the application, it will show the average from your code.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq` to the top.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that first you have tried `MyList.Average()` in you code behind file. which worked because by default in all code behind, `Linq` namespace is being used.

see on the top, you will see `using System.Linq;`

and then you have tried the same thing in your `Form.Designer.cs` and you faced this issue

> Method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Average' not found.

It is because in `Designer.cs` by default no namespaces are used.

As mentioned in comments, you can hard code Text of label in designer file, and then assign proper value in Form's Load Event (which is normally in code behind where Linq is already used).

But If you really want to do that in Designer.cs, add `using System.Linq;` at the top of you Designer file.